# Missing references when porting code to ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dropbox-api

I'm using a `DropboxClient` object in an MVC project and is working fine, but I need to use it in ASP.NET Core, and when I try to use exactly the same code in ASP.NET Core I'm getting some compile time errors, these are the errors:

1. > The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.
2. > The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.
3. > 'DropboxClient': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'
4. > The type 'Task<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.
5. > The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.

I think that all these errors are related to some configuration that I need to do in ASP.net Core, in MVC the code runs without problem.

This is the code:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            using (DropboxClient client = new DropboxClient("dddddddddddddsdadffsdf343"))
            {
                var full = client.Users.GetCurrentAccountAsync();
                var result = full.Result.Email;
                var other = full.Result.Country;
                var other2 = full.Result.Name;
            }
                return View();
        }
```

What do I need to change in ASP.net Core in order for this code to run?

Comment: Aren't the errors self-explanatory really?

Comment: You'll need to post your project.json

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using package manager console I've installed this package : `"Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1"` and now there are no errors.
I've run this command: `install-package Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility`.
I'm copying a short descritpion about this package:

> Enables compatiblity with portable libraries targeting previous .NET releases like .NET Framework 4.0 and Silverlight.
>   This package supports retargeting references to classic reference assemblies (mscorlib.dll, system.dll, etc) to new contract assemblies (System.Runtime.dll, System.IO, etc).